# Disable template layout, load component only - vue js

Tags: vue.js, components

I want to hide rest of the template, just want to view my component. How can I do that? Is there any way to disable the parent layout in vue js?

That's how I have set the route

[image]

Comment: You can allways use a simpler layout, no?

Comment: pretty new in vue.js, not really sure how to disable it for one page and enable for rest of the pages @ToniMichelCaubet